# Python Bloomberg API not connecting from ipython notebook

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

based on following code [example of a simple historical data request](https://code.google.com/p/pyalma/source/browse/trunk/InfoProviders/Bloomberg.py) and the Python API example provided by Bloomberg I constructed the bdh function below which works fine when directly called from ipython (see the testing lines after the function definition).

```
import blpapi
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from optparse import OptionParser


def parseCmdLine():
    parser = OptionParser(description="Retrieve reference data.")
    parser.add_option("-a",
                  "--ip",
                  dest="host",
                  help="server name or IP (default: %default)",
                  metavar="ipAddress",
                  default="localhost")
parser.add_option("-p",
                  dest="port",
                  type="int",
                  help="server port (default: %default)",
                  metavar="tcpPort",
                  default=8194) 

(options, args) = parser.parse_args()

return options

def bdh(secList, fieldList,startDate,endDate=dt.date.today().strftime('%Y%m%d'),periodicity='Daily'):
""" Sends a historical request to Bloomberg.
Returns a panda.Panel object.
"""

options = parseCmdLine()

# Fill SessionOptions
sessionOptions = blpapi.SessionOptions()
sessionOptions.setServerHost(options.host)
sessionOptions.setServerPort(options.port)

print "Connecting to %s:%s" % (options.host, options.port)
# Create a Session
session = blpapi.Session(sessionOptions)

# Start a Session
if not session.start():
    print "Failed to start session."
    return

try:
    # Open service to get historical data from
    if not session.openService("//blp/refdata"):
        print "Failed to open //blp/refdata"
        return

    # Obtain previously opened service
    refDataService = session.getService("//blp/refdata")

    # Create and fill the requestuest for the historical data
    request = refDataService.createRequest("HistoricalDataRequest")
    for s in secList:
        request.getElement("securities").appendValue(s)
    for f in fieldList:
        request.getElement("fields").appendValue(f)
    request.set("periodicityAdjustment", "ACTUAL")
    request.set("periodicitySelection", "DAILY")
    request.set("startDate", startDate)
    request.set("endDate", endDate)

    print "Sending Request:", request
    # Send the request
    session.sendRequest(request)

    # Process received events
    response={}
    while(True):
        # We provide timeout to give the chance for Ctrl+C handling:
        ev = session.nextEvent(500)
        if ev.eventType() == blpapi.Event.RESPONSE or ev.eventType() == blpapi.Event.PARTIAL_RESPONSE:
            for msg in ev:
                secData = msg.getElement('securityData')
                name = secData.getElement('security').getValue()
                response[name] = {}
                fieldData = secData.getElement('fieldData')
                for i in range(fieldData.numValues()):
                    fields = fieldData.getValue(i)
                    for n in range(1, fields.numElements()):
                        date = fields.getElement(0).getValue()
                        field = fields.getElement(n)
                    try:
                        response[name][field.name()][date] = field.getValue()
                    except KeyError:
                        response[name][field.name()] = {}
                        response[name][field.name()][date] = field.getValue()


        if ev.eventType() == blpapi.Event.RESPONSE:
            # Response completly received, so we could exit
            break

    #converting the response to a panda pbject
    tempdict = {}
    for r in response:
        td = {}
        for f in response[r]:
            td[f] = pd.Series(response[r][f])

        tempdict[r] = pd.DataFrame(td)
        data = pd.Panel(tempdict)


finally:
    # Stop the session
    session.stop()
    return(data)
#------------------------------------------------------------
secList = ['SP1 Index', 'GC1 Comdty']
fieldList = ['PX_LAST']
beg = (dt.date.today() - dt.timedelta(30)).strftime('%Y%m%d')
testData = bdh.bdh(secList,fieldList,beg)
testData = testData.swapaxes('items','minor')
print(testData['PX_LAST'])
```

However, when I try to run exactly the same example (see the lines after the bdh function definition) from ipython notebook, then I get following error:

```
    SystemExit                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-ad6708eabe39> in <module>()
----> 1 testData = bbg.bdh(tickers,fields,begin)
      2 #testData = testData.swapaxes('items','minor')
      3 #print(testData['PX_LAST'])

C:\Python27\bbg.py in bdh(secList, fieldList, startDate, endDate, periodicity)
     33     """
     34 
---> 35     options = parseCmdLine()
     36 
     37     # Fill SessionOptions

C:\Python27\bbg.py in parseCmdLine()
     24                       default=8194) 
     25 
---> 26     (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
     27 
     28     return options

C:\Python27\lib\optparse.pyc in parse_args(self, args, values)
   1400             stop = self._process_args(largs, rargs, values)
   1401         except (BadOptionError, OptionValueError), err:
-> 1402             self.error(str(err))
   1403 
   1404         args = largs + rargs

C:\Python27\lib\optparse.pyc in error(self, msg)
   1582         """
   1583         self.print_usage(sys.stderr)
-> 1584         self.exit(2, "%s: error: %s\n" % (self.get_prog_name(), msg))
   1585 
   1586     def get_usage(self):

C:\Python27\lib\optparse.pyc in exit(self, status, msg)
   1572         if msg:
   1573             sys.stderr.write(msg)
-> 1574         sys.exit(status)
   1575 
   1576     def error(self, msg):

SystemExit: 2
```

My understanding is that the options needed to connect to Bloomberg work fine if I call the bdh function from a local ipython session but are wrong if bdh is called from the kernel notebook initiates???

Hope to get some help, thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `parseCmdLine()`, it looks at `sys.argv`, which is probably not what you're expecting.

What about this?

```
def parseCmdLine():
    parser = OptionParser(description="Retrieve reference data.")
    parser.add_option("-a",
                  "--ip",
                  dest="host",
                  help="server name or IP (default: %default)",
                  metavar="ipAddress",
                  default="localhost")
parser.add_option("-p",
                  dest="port",
                  type="int",
                  help="server port (default: %default)",
                  metavar="tcpPort",
                  default=8194) 

(options, args) = parser.parse_args()

return options


def bdh(secList, fieldList,startDate,endDate=dt.date.today().strftime('%Y%m%d'),periodicity='Daily', host='localhost', port=8194):
""" Sends a historical request to Bloomberg.
Returns a panda.Panel object.
"""

# Fill SessionOptions
sessionOptions = blpapi.SessionOptions()
sessionOptions.setServerHost(host)
sessionOptions.setServerPort(port)

...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    options = parseCmdLine()

    secList = ['SP1 Index', 'GC1 Comdty']
    fieldList = ['PX_LAST']
    beg = (dt.date.today() - dt.timedelta(30)).strftime('%Y%m%d')
    testData = bdh.bdh(secList,fieldList,beg, host=options.host, port=options.port)
    testData = testData.swapaxes('items','minor')
    print(testData['PX_LAST'])
```